# How to change content on website built on Symfony framework

Tags: php, symfony1

I've been tasked with updating a client website, which is built on 'Symfony'. I don't even know which version (the symfony.php config file has a copyright date of 2004-2006, so presumably an early version). I'm not even a PHP developer, although I know my way around databases and server-side code reasonably well.

I need to make a simple update to a web page on this site, so I downloaded all the code and simply searched for the text I need to amend. This has been found in two places: once in a .php file under 'apps > frontend > modules > main > templates > thepage.php'. The other reference to this text is in a .sql back-up script, which suggests that the same content is also present in a database table somewhere.  Although the database doesn't seem to be on the web server, so I'm assuming it's a local database which has been used to push out changes to static files on the web server.  However, I updated the php file content and FTP'd back up to the server, but the changes I made aren't showing on the site!?

So, the question is, where is content generally stored in Symfony? How come there's the same content in a database and also in a php file too?  Is there some kind of cache going on?

Thanks very much for any pointers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

symfony has a built in cache, so that may be a problem

to find which version of symfony you are running ssh into the server and navigate to the root symfony directory (where you'll see the folders, apps, cache, config, web, et al) and run this:

```
php symfony -V
```

you are probably running version 1.0 but for what we need that probably won't matter

to clear the cache, which shouldn't affect anything in the site except slowing it down somewhat for the first users to hit a particular page after the clearing, type in this:

```
php symfony cc
```

as to the database having the same content as the template, I have no idea, it may be something specific to your site

Comment: Thanks Patrick.  Do you know if there's a way to clear the cache without getting involved with SSH, as that would be a major learning curve for me (and time is tight)?  If I could just delete a cache file, it would be much simpler.  Is there a standard place where symfony caches files?  I think it is version 1 by the way.

Comment: I've just done some reading and downloaded PUTTY SSH client.  I've logged in as root user to the server, fine, but the commands above don't seem to work - I just get 'Could not open input file: symfony'.  Any ideas much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: in the root symfony directory you should see a small file called symfony, if it's not there you can change the directory to get to the folder that has the symfony file, which allows you to run tasks from the command line.  the directory should be [symfony root]/lib/vendor/symfony/data/bin once you cd into that, php symfony cc and that should work

Comment: btw, there is a single place all the cache files are located but i would be reluctant to manually remove the cache files in case some of the files are not meant to be removed/changed.  they are located at [symfony root]/cache